# How to add an arrow and explanation to each term in an equation in beamer?

Tags: beamer

how to add an arrow and explanation to each term in an equation in beamer

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-node}
\begin{document}
\psset{nodesep=3pt}
\newrgbcolor{lila}{0.6 0.2 0.5}
\newrgbcolor{darkyellow}{1 0.9 0}
Die Bindungsenergie im Tröpfchenmodell setzt sich aus
folgenden Teilen zusammen:
\begin{itemize}
\item dem \rnode{b}{Oberflächenanteil}
\item Dem \rnode{a}{Volumenanteil},\\[1cm]
\def\xstrut{\vphantom{\frac{(A)^1}{(B)^1}}}
\begin{equation}
E =
\rnode[t]{ae}{\psframebox*[fillcolor=darkyellow,linestyle=none]{\xstrut a_vA}} +
\rnode[t]{be}{\psframebox*[fillcolor=lightgray,linestyle=none]{\xstrut -a_fA^{2/3}}} +
\rnode[t]{ce}{\psframebox*[fillcolor=green,linestyle=none]{\xstrut -a_c\frac{Z(Z-1)}{A^{1/3}}}} +
\rnode[t]{de}{\psframebox*[fillcolor=cyan,linestyle=none]{\xstrut -a_s\frac{(A-2Z)^2}{A}}} +
\rnode[t]{ee}{\psframebox*[fillcolor=yellow,linestyle=none]{\xstrut E_p}}
\end{equation}\\[0.25cm]
\item dem \rnode{c}{Coulomb-Anteil}
\item der \rnode{d}{Symmetrieenergie}
\item sowie einem \rnode{e}{Paarbildungsbeitrag}.
\end{itemize}
\nccurve[angleA=-90,angleB=90]{->}{a}{ae}
\nccurve[angleB=45]{->}{b}{be}
\nccurve[angleB=-90]{->}{c}{ce}
\nccurve[angleB=-90]{->}{d}{de}
\nccurve[angleB=-90]{->}{e}{ee}
\end{document}
```

this is the output of node5.tex

2

Comment: Hi, welcome to TeX.SE.  A few more sentences in your question will help you get the answers that you're looking for.  Have you tried anything?  What engine (apparently not pdflatex. xelatex?) and packages (tikz? pstricks?) are you using besides beamer?

Comment: i'm not using any packages.don't know which package to use

Answer (score 8):

[How to use TikZ with beamer to explain terms in equations](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/beamer-arrows/)

Comment: works with pdflatex only

Comment: @user4852: The article says it requires pdflatex, but it works in xelatex as well.

Comment: @user4852: If you look at the comments on that link you'll see that it is claimed that it does work with the other backend drivers as well.

Answer (score 6):

Here is an example:
http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi?file=pst-node/nodes#text

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\psset{arrowscale=2,arrows=->}
\def\VPh{\vphantom{\displaystyle\sum_{i=n}^m {i^2}}}
\def\psBox#1#2{\psframebox[fillcolor=#1,fillstyle=solid]{\VPh\displaystyle#2}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Foo}{bar}
\[
   \only<1->{\rnode{t1}{\psBox{green!30}{\sum_{i=n}^m {i^2}}} +} 
   \only<2->{\rnode{t2}{\psBox{blue!30}{\int_0^t \mathrm d\:\!\tau}} + 
             \Gamma\bigl(n +\frac{1}{2}\bigr)+ }
   \only<3->{\rnode{t3}{\psBox{red!30}{\frac{1}{2}m\|\mathbf v\|^2}}}
\]

\begin{itemize}[<+->]
   \item  Power \rnode[rc]{T1}{series} \nccurve[angleB=-75]{T1}{t1}
   \item  Definite \rnode[rc]{T2}{integral}\nccurve[angleB=-90]{T2}{t2} 
   \item  Non-relativistic kinetic \rnode[rc]{T3}{energy}\nccurve[angleB=-90]{T3}{t3}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: some packages  are used,i can't find it

Comment: can't find what?

Comment: ps-tricks,pst-mode

Comment: these packages are part of any tex distribution ... However, you mean `pstricks` and `pst-node`

Comment: @user4852: These packages can be found on CTAN.  Google "ctan pstricks" etc.

Comment: thn wat else to be added.that source code is not working

Comment: http://tug.org/PSTricks/pst-node/Examples/node5.tex is the complete working code. What else do you need?

Comment: c the output i obtained

Comment: @user4852: what you posted above is not the complete code. that are only fragments ... I'll update my answer and show a _complete_ example

Comment: i'm using kile under ubuntu