# Arrows between a list and a picture in beamer

Tags: beamer

How can I draw arrows between an item in an `itemize` environment and spots
on a picture using tikz?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%\usepackage{beamerthemeshadow}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\begin{document}
\section{section}
\begin{frame}
 \frametitle{frame title}

 \begin{columns}
 \column{.4\textwidth}
    \begin{block}{block title}
          \begin{itemize}
        \item <1-> stone
        \item <2-> more stones
        \item <3-> water
      \end{itemize}
    \end{block}
  \column{.6\textwidth}
      \begin{figure}[h]
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{25}%
    \caption{Landscape}
      \end{figure}
  \end{columns}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I want to achieve something like this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Some inspiration are presented here: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1220/what-are-your-favourite-tikz-pgf-answers

Comment: Possible duplicate [How to add an arrow and explanation to each term in an equation in beamer?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15695/9043)

Comment: Thanks for inspiration Marco. I found a solution at: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/connecting-text-and-graphics/

Comment: @schmendrich: Please type up a descriptive solution from your inspired source and post it as an answer - future readers may find your example useful. Self-answers are perfectly admissible, and a well-written answer may earn you additional reputation.

Answer (score 9):

The solution I found:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{beamerthemeshadow}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,backgrounds}

\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture]
\tikzstyle{na} = [baseline=-.5ex]
\section{section}
\begin{frame}
 \frametitle{frame title}

 \begin{columns}
   \begin{column}{.4\textwidth}
    \begin{block}{block title}<1-5>
          \begin{itemize}
        \item <1-| alert@2> stone\,\tikz[na] \coordinate (Lstone);
        \item <1-| alert@3> more stones\,\tikz[na] \coordinate (Lmorestones);
        \item <1-| alert@4> water\,\tikz[na] \coordinate (Lwater);
      \end{itemize}
    \end{block}
     \end{column}
    \begin{column}{.6\textwidth}
      %\begin{figure}[h]
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
            \node [inner sep=0pt,above right]{
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{25}%
    };
    \path (1.45,1.1) coordinate (stone);
    \path (3.45,1.1) coordinate (morestone);
    \path (3.5,2.6) coordinate (water);
    \end{tikzpicture}
     % \end{figure}
     \end{column}
  \end{columns}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
        \draw<2> [thin, red,opacity=.8, fill=red,fill opacity=0.3](stone) circle (4pt);
        \path<2>[->,>=latex', red, shorten >=4pt, opacity=.6] (Lstone) edge [out=0, in=130] (stone);

        \draw<3> [thin, red,opacity=.8, fill=red,fill opacity=0.3](morestone) circle (4pt);
        \path<3>[->, >=latex', red, shorten >=4pt, opacity=.6] (Lmorestones) edge [out=0, in=150] (morestone);

        \draw<4> [thin, red,opacity=.8, fill=red,fill opacity=0.3](water) circle (4pt);
        \path<4>[->,>=latex',red, shorten >=4pt, opacity=.6] (Lwater) edge [out=0, in=200] (water);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

There are some issues i have to play with, to become more elegant: 
Setting nodes in relation to the picture; at the moment I will have to re-coordinate the nodes if I change the picture size. 
And I don't like the "shorten solution" for the arrows because i have to change the value manually if I change the diameter of the circle.

Comment: Take a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9559/drawing-on-an-image-with-tikz for a way of having relative coordinates on the image.

Comment: Thanks. It seems, that the scope environment is what I was looking for.