# Add rectangle color box inside align and explain using an arrow

Tags: beamer, equations, bounding-box, colorbox

Hi i'm creating a beamer presentation and trying to make my equation beautiful. Is it possible to make color rectangle or circle in align and then write something about that part of the equation.

```
 \begin{align}
    \bigwedge\limits_{i,j} E(i,j) = \exists_{m,c} m c^{2} 
    \tag{Eqn}\label{energy} 
 \end{align}
```

I want to create a color box around E(i,j) and then use a pointer/arrow and tell that E(i,j) is a variable representing energy, m represents mass and c represents change. I have tried \colorbox but do not able to get how to point the box and comment. Thanks.

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15695/how-to-add-an-arrow-and-explanation-to-each-term-in-an-equation-in-beamer

Comment: or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254844/explain-formula-using-beamer

Comment: or http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/beamer-arrows/

Comment: or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133393/text-below-equation-with-hf-tikz

Comment: or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254844/explain-formula-using-beamer

Comment: or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86188/labelling-with-arrows-in-an-automated-way

Comment: Can you please go back to your previous questions and look if the answers solve your problems and accept them, if they do?

Comment: And as you have been asked before, please don't just post code fragments but [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: Did any of the linked questions help you in particular?

Comment: I used first two. And there were really helpful. I crashed them early (before asking question) but was not sure how to use them in align setting. Thanks.

Comment: Good to hear the other question/answers helped you! I marked your question as a duplicate so future visitors will be lead to where you found an answer to your question.